# Keycloak + mysql on docker compose. No data saved

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, keycloak

So I am trying to set up a Keycloak with Mysql back-end using docker compose but no matter what I do, Keycloak refuses to actually create any tables or store any data in the database even though they both start just fine.

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, I would be eternally grateful.

```
version: '2'
services:
        lab-mysql:
                container_name: lab-mysql
                restart: always
                image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
                environment:
                        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
                        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
                        MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
                        MYSQL_USER: keycloak
                        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
                volumes:
                        - ./lab-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
                ports:
                        - 3306:3306
        keycloak:
                container_name: lab-keycloak
                restart: always
                image: jboss/keycloak:3.4.3.Final
                depends_on:
                        - lab-mysql
                environment:
                        DB_VENDOR: mysql
                        DB_ADDR: lab-mysql
                        DB_PORT: 3306
                        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
                        DB_USER: keycloak
                        DB_PASSWORD: password
                        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
                        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
                ports:
                        - 8080:8080
                        - 8443:8443
                        - 9990:9990
                volumes:
                        - ./lab-keycloak:/data
                links:
                        - lab-mysql
```

Comment: Are you sure they both start up properly? You have a `restart: always` option meaning if they fail somehow, they'll instantly stand up again. That would leave you unaware of the problem until you spot it in logs. You should inspect logs carefully as there might be some warning stating what's the problem. I'll try running your configuration.

Comment: Try adding `KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG` into your keycloak environment variables as it'll increase log verbosity and might reveal the issue.

Comment: I didn't realise you could set log level in env vars. Thanks. I'll do some error searching with that and see if I come up with anything.

Comment: I started your config and this is what I've found in debug logs: `[KEYCLOAK DOCKER IMAGE] Using the embedded H2 database`, meaning it doesn't connect to the MySQL db, only using it's embedded one.

Comment: The problem is - db initializes very long and keycloak is not waiting for it, i'm testing now a separate setup with db already initialized and waiting for keycloak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your Keycloak to try using your MySQL DB without utilizing it's own embedded DB (reference to my comments), you should change a variable:

`DB_VENDOR: mysql`

into

`DB_VENDOR: MYSQL`

**Additional information and hints**

Additionally those services starting process should be separated (two `docker-compose` files or one service waiting for another ) because **Keycloak is not aware of when does your MySQL finish initializing the DB** - meaning it'll proceed and throw exception when it will not be able to access the MySQL DB as the DB will still be starting up. `depends_on` is not sufficient here because it's not waiting until service is `ready`, well explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

The `mysql-compose.yml` I used:

```
version: '2'
services:
        lab-mysql:
                image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
                environment:
                        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: keycloak
                        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
                        MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
                        MYSQL_USER: keycloak
                        MYSQL_PASSWORD: keycloak
                ports:
                        - 3306:3306
```

The `keycloak-compose.yml` I used:

```
version: '2'
services:
        keycloak:
                image: jboss/keycloak:3.4.3.Final
                environment:
                        DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
                        DB_ADDR: 10.28.0.35
                        DB_PORT: 3306
                        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
                        DB_USER: keycloak
                        DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
                        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
                        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
                ports:
                        - 8070:8080
                        - 8443:8443
                        - 9990:9990
```

Note the change of `DB_VENDOR` which is crucial here as now it actually alters to using MySQL. Also note `DB_ADDR` variable so that you change it to a address where the DB is run.

**Super important info**

I didn't manage to actually run it successfully because of a network problem I'm still resolving, making it impossible for `keycloak` to reach `mysql` service over the network. Although OP might find it very useful as this change will alter connection from `embedded H2` into `external MySQL` which is the asked question. And **if the DB is accessible, it will actually utilize it**. I'll be adding edits to this answer when I resolve my network issue to keep it up to date.

**Side note**

It's worth noting that Keycloak `3.4.3` (used here) uses mysql driver in version `5.1` which requires `MySQL server` with version `5.6`, `5.7` and higher.